# Comparable<T> vs Raw Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

I was recently writing a simple generic selection sort method for the fun of it, when I got a little confused about something. Here's my code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int minIndex = i; // Assume that the first element is the minimum for now.

        // Find smallest element in unsorted sub-list.
        for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); k++) {
            if (list.get(k).compareTo(list.get(minIndex)) < 0) {
                minIndex = k;
            }
        }

        // Swap smallest element with the first element in unsorted sub-list.
        T temp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(minIndex));
        list.set(minIndex, temp);
    }
}
```

The function itself works fine, but I got a little confused about the generics. I use:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

to ensure that the given List has a comparable type. But what if I were to use a raw Comparable instead? That is:

```
<T extends Comparable>
```

What exactly would be the repercussions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, you lose some type safety.

When you have your `T temp = list.get(i)`, what can you do with `temp.compareTo`?

- with `T extends Comparable<T>`, `temp` is `Comparable<T>`, meaning you can only pass another `T` into `compareTo`
- with `T extends Comparable`, `temp` is  `Comparable`, meaning you can pass anything into `compareTo`

The first of those is almost definitely what you want, because comparable types can only handle objects of the same type. For instance, `String.compareTo` can only handle String inputs -- if you pass in an Integer, you'll get a ClassCastException.

Given that the only safe input to `temp.compareTo` is a reference of type `T`, there is usually no good reason to use the raw type. It's *occasionally* beneficial for getting around the type system, but in most cases it removes type safety without giving you anything in return.

Comment: Could you show *how* it provides type safety? As in cases when compiler prevents from passing a non-T type

Comment: @parsecer Say you had a typo in the OP's code: `if (list.get(k).compareTo(minIndex) < 0)` (`minIndex` instead of `list.get(minIndex)`). With `T extends Comparable<T>`, you'd get a compile-time error, since the compiler requires a `T` that's comparable only against other `T`s. With `T extends Comparable`, you wouldn't get an error (though you would get a warning), because the compiler only requires that `T` is a _raw_ `Comparable`, and the argument to that is just `Object`. So `minIndex` gets boxed and passed to `list.get(k).compareTo(Object)`, which throws a ClassCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`<T extends Comparable>` would be applicable for a mixed type of comparable objects. For example this would be satisfied by both `Integer` instances as well as `String` instances whereas `<T extends Comparable<T>>` ensures that the types are comparable with each other.

An an example, the following would compile but would throw runtime exceptions because of a class cast exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<? extends Comparable> l = createList(Integer.valueOf(1), "Man");
    Collections.sort(l);
}

protected static <T extends Comparable<?>> List<T> createList(T ... args)
{
    return Arrays.asList(args);
}
```

By restricting to `<T extends Comparable<T>` this becomes a runtime check as changing the method to this prevents the previous code from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Another consequence could be with inheriting a super class, which would implement the nongeneric Comparable(obj).

```
public abstract Ship implements Comparable {
  public int compareTo(obj) {
    return ..
  }
}
```

then a subclass would have to implement its own Comparable as well. Without it like this:

```
public class Boat extends Ship {}
```

The compiler will complain on Boat that:

```
Boat is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable
```

While with using generic version with specific type, when compareTo(T obj) would exist in abstract class T, the inheriting classes wouldn't have to implement its own compareTo unless they want a custom implementation.